# ASP.NET Ajax Call Session Expired

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a code in which i am calling an asp.net method. some times session expired so it giving wired messages and response. When session expires this code is returning aspx page not the data. So how can i check in this method that session is expired ??

```
function loadGrid() {
    showPopUpMain();
    arrConstructedPages = [];
    var URL = 'XHR/GoogleMediaAjaxCalls.aspx?functionCode=LoadGoogleMedianvoices&searchstring=' + escape(GetSearchString())
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        data: null,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        error: errLoadData,
        success: loaddata
    });
}
```

[image: Data Returned on method success instead it's session expired.]

Comment: You can check it where you call this function. So if you have no session, simply don't call it.

Comment: i am making ajax call using Jquery i don't know how to check session in javascript ?? any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is where you call it:

```
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
.
.
<% if(Session["something"]!=null){%>
window.setTimeOut('loadData("")',300);
<% } %>
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's not working. It seems 'if(Session["something"]!=null' is always true whether session expired or not.

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: yes the result is same ajax call is returning with same data containing aspx (html and javascript).